# How to get a value from an array in Mule 4

Tags: mule, dataweave, mule-esb, mulesoft, mule4

I wanted to get a value in an array without using absolute array positioning.
Here is my json payload.

```
{ 
  "xyz":{ 
    "abc":[ 
      { 
        "account":[ 
          { 
            "value":"savings"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

How to get the value savings using Data Weave..

Comment: and how do you like to select the element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also do that.
I supposed you don't want to use at all indexes and that there is only one key value in the payload:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json

var data = {"xyz": {"abc":["account":[{"value":"savings"}]]}}
---
data..value reduce $
```

Comment: Hi Sebastien., Thank you for the answer ! It is working fine but may I know what are those dots in middle?? If I am giving 3,4 dots then also it is working fine

Comment: Please read https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.2/dataweave-selectors

Answer (score 2):

This dataweave:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
payload..value[0]
```

will produce:

`savings`